# How to use default android themes?

Tags: android

Hy

I created an android project, and I saw thet, tehe are two themes.xml file. In emulator, when I switch day and night mode, my application color schema is changes too.

I thought it is greate, because with thease themes it will be easy to create a day/night app, but I don't know how it works.

How can I define a new color item inside themes, and use this schema for layout background?

For example: There is an item in both themes

```
<item name="colorPrimary">#303F9F</item>
```

And I would like to create a new item for both themes.xml, and use it to set up fragment background color, but the intellisense doesn't find this element directly.

```
<item name="backgroundColor">#303F9F</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change color easily from where you define your theme in 'styles.xml'.

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorSecondary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorSecondaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorSecondaryAccent</item>
</style>
```

I have two themes in my app so if i change the color or anything in my theme i will define that color in my selected theme for example:
i want to change the background color of 'AppThemeDark' i just define the color like this

```
<item name="background">@color/"#fff67"</item>
```

Comment: I understand that, but how can I set up this background item for the constraint layout? 
```android:background= ?```

Comment: 'android:background="@color/background" ' Add this in constraints layout

Comment: I tried to add, but it says : "Cannot resolve symbol '@color/background' "

I already defined both thems.xml file
```<item name="background">@color/purple_700</item>```
```<item name="background">@color/green_text_color</item>```

Comment: add this in your color.xml file

Comment: I added, it is true, that after that I can use this for the constraint layout, but it doesn't change, and it doesn't use the colors of themes.xml

Answer (score 0):

copy this line in your first screen

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
```

Comment: Sorry, it isn't help me, because I don't want to change theme programtically, I just want to use dinamic color according to day/night setup

Answer (score 0):

Ok In constraintlayout background tag is not worked so I will fix this problem with the use of View.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#AAA">

<View
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:background="#FFF"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView1" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:padding="8dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
tools:text="TextView" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView2"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1"
tools:text="TextView" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView3"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView1"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
tools:text="TextView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```